# AS3 child TextField doesn't scale normally

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield, scaling

I have a sprite with a textfield child on it. This textfield uses htmlText and is multilined. When I scale the sprite the textfield scales as well, but not perfectly. I end up getting the bottom few lines of the text cut off when I resize the sprite to a smaller size.

Is the automatic scaling of textfields supported by as3? I came up with some work around where I do a string.replace() on the htmlText and inject my own fontsize, but it would be amazing (and probably more efficient) if this just worked when I scale the parent sprite.

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use embedded font for the text displayed in the textfield?  If not, Flash would not be able to scale the text as "glyph", hence the text scaling would not be as proportional as the sprite.

Comment: I thought that embedded fonts were only "incase" the user doesn't have that font on their computer. Arial is universal across all computers I believe.

Comment: Not only embedded fonts address the "missing font", embedded font also allows Flash to precisely control font rendition as font is compiled to Flash's native high-performance model.  Conversely, non-embedded font would force Flash to rely on the OS to render text.  where the text would not have be anti-alias, and the text cannot be rotated or faded.